# How to get employee ID with increment of 20% and how many times he got the increment in Sql/Python

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a table with below values:-

[image]

I want to write a code in python/pyspark where I need to find the employee code who got the increment 20% or more than that. Also, I need how many times he got the increment.

Answer (score 1):

Use Window functions.

```
w=Window.partitionBy('emp_id').orderBy(to_date('salary_month_year'))
df1 = (df.withColumn('new_salary',lag('salary').over(w)).fillna(0)#Find previous salary in each row
         .withColumn('%increase', when(col('new_salary')==0,0)
         .otherwise(round((col('salary')-col('new_salary'))/col('salary'),1)*100))#Where group starts make it 0, and rest compute increment
          .withColumn('incr_count',sum((col("%increase")>0).cast('int')).over(w))#Compute increment count
          .where(col("%increase")>20).drop('new_salary')#Filter where salary >20% and drop unwanted column
      ).show()


+------+-----------------+------+---------+----------+
|emp_id|salary_month_year|salary|%increase|incr_count|
+------+-----------------+------+---------+----------+
|     1|           Mar-22|   400|     50.0|         2|
|     1|           Apr-22|   550|     30.0|         2|
|     2|           Feb-22|   500|     30.0|         1|
|     4|           Feb-22|   800|     30.0|         1|
+------+-----------------+------+---------+----------+
```